# Multiple records same id retrieval

Tags: oracle, query

I have a table with the following structure

| USERID | CONTACT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LANDLINE | +12312322334 |
| 1 | MOBILE | +11234567890 |
| 1 | EMAIL | user1@test.com |
| 2 | LANDLINE | +12312322335 |
| 2 | MOBILE | +11234567899 |
| 3 | LANDLINE | +12312322336 |
| 3 | MOBILE | +11234567898 |

I want to have a result set of all users that have an email contact and list
the result set as

| USERID | MOBILE | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | +11234567890 | user1@test.com |

Tried looking it up but can't remember the term of the needed query for thus, which made it hard for me find the solution.

Can anyone help and suggest the most efficient query for this scenario? This is for oracle db by the way

Comment: Is the term you are trying to remember, *pivot* by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, what you need is a self-join:

```sql
SELECT
    contact_email.USERID
    ,contact_email.VALUE AS EMAIL
    ,contact_mobile.VALUE AS MOBILE
FROM
    contacts AS contact_email
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    contacts AS contact_mobile
    ON contact_mobile.USERID = contact_email.USERID
    AND contact_mobile.CONTACT = 'MOBILE'
WHERE
    contact_email.contact = 'EMAIL'
;
```

The choice of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` means that you will also get contacts for which no matching mobile phone record can be found. If you want to omit such contacts, use an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be conditional aggregation (without it, result would be displayed in several rows) along with `EXISTS` which filters out users who don't have `EMAIL` as a contact option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (userid, contact, value) as
  2    (select 1, 'LANDLINE', '+12312322334'   from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'MOBILE'  , '+11234567890'   from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'EMAIL'   , 'user1@test.com' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'LANDLINE', '+12312322335'  from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'MOBILE'  , '+11234567899'  from dual union all
  7     select 3, 'LANDLINE', '+12312322336'  from dual union all
  8     select 3, 'MOBILE'  , '+11234567898'  from dual
  9    )
```

Query:

```
 10  select a.userid,
 11    max(case when a.contact = 'MOBILE' then a.value end) as mobile,
 12    max(case when a.contact = 'EMAIL'  then a.value end) as email
 13  from test a
 14  where exists (select null
 15                from test b
 16                where b.userid = a.userid
 17                  and b.contact = 'EMAIL'
 18               )
 19  group by a.userid;

    USERID MOBILE         EMAIL
---------- -------------- --------------
         1 +11234567890   user1@test.com

SQL>
```